# Node.js: Hooking repl to a remote node server

Tags: security, networking, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

Let's say I have a node server running at mysite.com. Is there a way to set up that server so that I can use [node's repl api](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/repl.html) to *securely* connect to it from my local machine?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, if you used this example:

```
net.createServer(function (socket) {
  repl.start("node via TCP socket> ", socket);
}).listen(5001, "localhost");
```

And firewalled that port `5001`, you should be able to securely connect to it using ssh:

```
ssh user@host nc localhost 5001
```

In this case, the security relies on your firewall, and ssh.

Comment: Maybe even better to bind with `127.0.0.1` too.