# node.js attach REPL to script

Tags: linux, node.js

How do I start a node.js script and still be able to execute commands into the terminal ? I am looking for a node.js REPL that is also there for my custom script, so that I can inspect/log the state of my program for instance.

This is something similar to [this JVM question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131302/attach-a-clojure-scala-repl-to-a-running-jvm), but for node.js.

I have tried `node -i server.js` without results. Do I need to have custom code in my script or is it feasible without that ? I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302458/node-js-hooking-repl-to-a-remote-node-server), but it requires custom code, which I'd like to avoid.

Also, bonus points for reattaching a node script launched by an init script (I can see it in the process list : `node -i server.js`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a repl loop from within your program

http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html

Comment: Like in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302458/node-js-hooking-repl-to-a-remote-node-server but that requires custom code, right ? Is it possible with an already running node process ?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to attach a repl to an already existing process if that is what you are asking.  The code in that answer creates a server which serves a repl when someone connects.  You could connect and disconnect from that multiple times(since the server will just keep listening).

Comment: Yes attach a REPL to an existing process is what I am asking. I'm not sure it is possible though.

Comment: I will accept your answer for now, but I would still be happy to find something that does this without having special code.

Answer (score 1):

Does the other way round work for you?

Start the REPL and then load the script and then execute your commands. Use `load` to load your script.

Inside REPL, try

```
.load server.js
```

Comment: My first thought is that if an extra bootstrap step is needed, I would prefer it in the code / startup script. Thank you though for the .load method, it looks interesting. I'll think about it.